# mysql - query 3 databases using union all - optimization

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query as below that needs to be run on 3 different databases (db1,db2, and db3) and query 2 tables that are exactly the same in the 3 databases:**sales_order_item** and **sales_order_item**

```
(
                SELECT
                    COUNT(DISTINCT soi.fk_sales_order) AS total_sales
                 FROM
                    db1.sales_order_item soi
                left join db1.sales_order_item_status sois 
                    ON soi.fk_sales_order_item_status = sois.id_sales_order_item_status
                WHERE
                    sois.name NOT IN ('invalid', 'test_invalid', 'new', 'placed', 'exchange_return_pending', 'exportable')
                AND DATE(date_add(created_at, INTERVAL 04 HOUR)) = DATE(date_add(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 04 HOUR))
            )
```

I am running the above query using **union all** for 3 different databases as mentioned.

The problem is that the tables, each of them hold data in the range of 40 to 80 million rows and the above query takes around 1.5 hours to execute.

I am not sure if there is a way to further optimize the above query even though the columns that are being used in the query are all indexed.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Doing `left join` will return all the rows of `db1.sales_order_item_status` table. What you get is the distinct count of the `db1.sales_order_item_status` table filtered with the `where` conditions you gave. Is this what you require?